# use an R script on all files in directory

Tags: r, file, loops, directory

Hi I have the following R script

```
emboss<-read.table("emboss_002.ss",header=T)
x<-table(emboss[,2],emboss[,3])/NROW(emboss[,3])
y<-as.vector(t(x))
nms <- expand.grid(colnames(x), rownames(x))
names(y) <- paste( nms[,2],nms[,1],sep="")
write.table(t(y), file = "nontpsec.csv",append=TRUE)
```

where I have over 300 files called emboss_[i].ss

How do I loop through the folder to run this script over every file? Each output goes into the same .csv file.

By the way - here is my data frame (x)

```
x

              C           E           H
  A 0.057971014 0.017391304 0.026086957
  C 0.005797101 0.002898551 0.002898551
  D 0.046376812 0.000000000 0.002898551
  E 0.063768116 0.002898551 0.020289855
  F 0.011594203 0.005797101 0.005797101
  G 0.069565217 0.002898551 0.002898551
  H 0.028985507 0.000000000 0.000000000
  I 0.017391304 0.008695652 0.002898551
  K 0.014492754 0.002898551 0.002898551
  L 0.043478261 0.011594203 0.034782609
  M 0.005797101 0.002898551 0.002898551
  N 0.017391304 0.000000000 0.005797101
  P 0.055072464 0.000000000 0.000000000
  Q 0.046376812 0.002898551 0.008695652
  R 0.049275362 0.011594203 0.023188406
  S 0.043478261 0.005797101 0.002898551
  T 0.034782609 0.017391304 0.014492754
  V 0.037681159 0.014492754 0.008695652
  W 0.014492754 0.008695652 0.002898551
  Y 0.026086957 0.008695652 0.011594203
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: opening, writing to, and closing the file 300 times is going to be slow. You better open a file connection.

Comment: not entirely interested in speed at the moment - but thanks for the pointer. will look into file connections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is untested, so it may be a bit off.
I would make a new function, collect all the files and apply the function to each file.

```
runForAll <- function(x) {
  emboss <- read.table(x,header=T)
  x <- table(emboss[,2],emboss[,3])/NROW(emboss[,3])
  y <- as.vector(t(x))
  nms <- expand.grid(colnames(x), rownames(x))
  names(y) <- paste( nms[,2],nms[,1],sep="")
  return(t(y))
}

my.files <- list.files(pattern = ".ss")
outputs <- lapply(my.files, FUN = runForAll)   

library(plyr)
one.header.output <- rbind.fill.matrix(outputs)
write.table(one.header.output, file = "nontpsec.csv")
```

You can also run this via `R CMD`.

Comment: Why the of `sapply` here? isn't better/safer to use `lapply`  here?

Comment: thanks - can see what you are doing here. I'm getting Error in `[.data.frame`(emboss, , 2) : undefined columns selected
In addition: Warning message:
In write.table(t(y), file = "nontpsec.csv", append = TRUE) :
  appending column names to file

Comment: @bruce: do you want one header for your file, or one for each row? If one header, I think you will have to analyze all your data at once to find all possible combinations for the columns 2 and 3.

Comment: preferably just one header, although in my test cases the current code generates a header line every other line. not ideal but I can get rid of them using an excel filter.

Comment: @flodel - thanks although still getting: Error in `[.data.frame`(emboss, , 2) : undefined columns selected
Calls: lapply -> FUN -> table -> [ -> [.data.frame


I have put an example dataframe into my question

Comment: That means `my.files` contains a file that does not have at least two columns. Try making the `list.files` pattern `".ss"` a little stronger, maybe `"emboss_\\d+\\.ss"`. If it still errors out, you ought to find which file is wrong on your own and fix it.

Comment: @flodel - that worked perfectly. thanks so much. I have accepted your edited answer.